# Source code email notifications benefits to your team?

Tags: team-management, project-team, team-building

I've recently suggested to my team that we should try SVN source code email notifications on commit. I thought it would help the team to feel more connected, informed, etc.

However, majority of people said clear: no. They feel it would be too much emails.

I tried the notifications in previous companies I worked for, and now I feel I can't do without it.

What benefits do the notifications bring to your team?

Comment: I've never used them, but I had a collegue who used the 'notifications fire hose' (from vc and build) to re-educate an overly micromanaging manager who wanted to know what the team were doing 'in detail'. It worked.

Comment: I am a developer on the project, it's not up to me to decide. All I know is that I miss this feature.

Comment: I feel that 50-100 messages daily routed to some Outlook subfolder should not bother people too much, definitely should not stop the team from trying something new, something that might improve the teamwork. Just surprised that people are not willing to at least try it out.

Comment: Hi Dani, I believe the question, as it stands, might be considered offtopic. On the other hand, if you really want to know how commits are going on your project, you should try [CommitMonitor](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/CommitMonitor.html).

Answer (score 3):

No matter what sort of benefits source-control-emails may or may not bring to your team, they are going to be *strongly* counterpointed by the negative feelings your team will undoubtedly have from you introducing something which they *specifically requested you not to introduce*.

If you absolutely cannot live without these emails, then try explaining to your team *why*. Perhaps in doing so, your team will see the same benefits you do, and you will have successfully created buy-in. If they *don't*, consider finding a solution where *only you* receive these emails (may be as simple as setting up the team's email clients to block these emails). This way, you get your emails, and the team gets their smaller inboxes.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. Opt-in opt-out mailing list would do.